# How many different cats can a cat keep track of?

Tags: cats, psychology, multi-pet-families, socializing

I have four cats, adopted as kittens over a period of time, with some gap between adoptions.

Cat #1 (the first one) dislikes cats #2, #3, and #4 (hisses at them, and generally avoids them).

Cat #2 dislikes #3 and #4.

Cat #3 dislikes #4.

Cat #4 dislikes no one.

So it appears that each cat can remember, recognize, and position itself in the hierarchy in comparison to three other cats.

I'm assuming that at some point the cats would be unable to keep track of every other cat.

At how many cats in one household would the average cat no longer be able to keep perfect track?

Comment: I don't think they are keeping a track. Cats don't like to fight, especially if odds are against them, because they don't have a concept of honour as humans and injuries might be fatal in the wild. I believe Cat #1 is the most confident one, so unless some other cat with the exact same confidence level arrives, nobody would engage him. Cats also show more confidence in their designated territory, so for any newcomer to challenge him, he should be significantly larger. So, they don't really keep track, at each correspondence, they just gauge their confidence and the confident one hisses.

Comment: I don't really see correlation between their confidence (or at least my estimation of it) and their order of arrival... it's true that the less confident hiss less, but they still exhibit other "dislike" patterns, like trying to avoid the cats that came later, whereas later cats don't really try to avoid earlier cats...

Comment: After a certain time, they will settle down and their confidence will be less correlated with their order of arrival. Still, new arrivals usually start at the bottom of the pecking order.

Comment: it's been a few years now... they're settled and there's not much drama. Once in a couple of months they might even play with each other, but usually they maintain distance and occasionally hiss or otherwise vocally complain if they accidentally find themselves too close, and always according to the #1 > #2 > #3 > #4 hierarchy. I guess it might be a "coincidence", four cats is not a huge population to reach conclusions by, but I do know that (some?) animals recognize individuals in groups, so it seems sensible...

Comment: You are right, they differentiate each of them. I guess by scent and by other means. But the order you suggested can exist with 1000 cats as well. Confident ones will carve up some large territory for themselves and less confidents will try to make due with whatever they are left with. Equally confident ones will definitely stay out of each other's way.

Comment: Yes, but they haven't actually divided the apartment into territories... sure each cat has its favorite couple of places but generally all of them roam (and sleep) everywhere, so it doesn't seem like they remember or smell territory, but really specific other cats. Maybe by scent, like you said, but even if it's by scent, there must be a limit to how many different cats they can remember as "beneath them" and how many "above"...